# Can I call a 64bit DLL from a 32bit version of Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, 64-bit, vba

I'm in the unusual situation of having a 32bit install of Excel and some libraries I call have been compiled as 64bit libraries but when I try to call the functions I get an error "Cannot find xyz.dll".

I know you can't call 32bit processes (easily) from 64bit ones, but what about vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do that. A 64 bit dll cannot be loaded into a 32 bit process.

(You can't do the converse either by the way, but you are correct that you can call a 32 bit *process* from a 64 bit *process*, and vice-versa).